# How to connect to database on NAS from Vagrant-box

Tags: database, ip, vagrant, virtualhost, nas

I am currently developing a website with a virtual server based on Vagrant. Before that I always used my NAS-webserver to develop my sites.
I want to keep using my database on the NAS cause it's easy to handle through phpMyAdmin that is installed as an app on the NAS.

When ssh'ed into my virtualbox I can ping to the internal ip from my NAS, being 192.168.0.10. Making a database connection to it, does not work.

Usually I take static ip for my VirtualBox that does not belong to the range of my internal network, e.g. 192.168.33.23. I tried to change this to an ip that is in the range but then I get an error saying:

```
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change 
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of a bridged or non-hostonly network.
```

What is the best method to solve this issue? I read the Vagrant Docs and other posts but I didn't get it up and running.

** UPDATE **

I added this line to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network 'public_network'
```

This invokes a bridged mode. After choosing 'en0: Wi-Fi (Airport)' as adapter when starting the VM, the ip of my VM is now 192.168.0.100 but I still can't connect to my database @192.168.0.10.
I already did a credential check by placing all files on the NAS-webserver and all worked well.

Comment: Verify that the chosen IP is not in use in your host network with the vagrant box not running.  You have probably chosen the IP of another device in your network.

Comment: @Beel I used the x.x.x.20 which is unused. I added the second part of the errormessage I got when trying to vagrant up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- set the network to bridged mode
- grant the VM ip address access in the mysql users table

So I just added the same user in phpMyAdmin but now with the VM ip address as hostname.